# FormatException of DateTime.Parse. Check which part is wrong in my date string

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I'd like to validate a date string in my TextBox.

If I have **2018-06-07** string in my `TextBox`, I can parse it with **success** with `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.Parse`.

But if I have **2018-12-35** in my `TextBox`, the `DateTime.Prase` throws `FormatException` that is absolutely right.
How can I determine which part of DateTime is wrong. For Example how to determine if Day or Month is wrong.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that as far as I know.

Comment: No existing function for it. You will have to split the string and check each one of them separately

Comment: thanks everybody I've already write a parser, validator just thinking about maybe there is a shorter, better way.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse` tries a number of formats - some to do with the current culture, and some more invariant ones. It looks like it's including an attempt to parse with the ISO-8601 format of "yyyy-MM-dd" - which is valid for your first example, but not for your second. (There aren't 35 days in December.)

As it's trying to parse multiple formats, it doesn't necessarily make sense to isolate which part is "wrong" - different parts could be invalid for different formats.

How you should tackle this depends on where your data comes from. If it's meant to be machine-readable data, it's best to enforce a culture-invariant format (ideally ISO-8601) rather than using `DateTime.Parse`: specify the format you expect using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`. You still won't get information about which part is wrong, but it's at least easier to reason about. (That will also make it easier to know which calendar system is being used.)

If the data is from a user, ideally you'd present them with some form of calendar UI so they don't have to enter the text at all. At that point, only users who are entering the text directly would produce invalid input, and you may well view it as "okay" for them to get a blanket error message of "this value is invalid".

I don't believe .NET provides any indication of where the value was first seen to be invalid, even for a single value. [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) provides more information when parsing via the exception, but not in a machine-readable way. (The exception message provides diagnostic information, but that's probably not something to show the user.)

In short: you probably can't do exactly what you want to do here (without writing your own parser or validator) so it's best to try to work out alternative approaches. Writing a general purpose validator for this would be really hard.

If you *only* need to handle ISO-8601 dates, it's relatively straightforward:

- Split the input by dashes. If there aren't three dashes, it's invalid
- Parse each piece of the input as an integer. That can fail (on each piece separately)
- Validate that the year is one you're happy to handle
- Validate that the month is in the range 1-12
- Validate that the day is valid for the month (use `DateTime.DaysInMonth` to help with that)

Each part of that is reasonably straightforward, but what you *do* with that information will be specific to your application. We don't really have enough context to help write the code without making significant assumptions.